# Query on Unix Timestamp Range in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am looking to write a query in MySQL that gives me results that are within the past 30 days. There is a field called start_date which is in unixtime and I need to say something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE (start_date) is within the past 30 days
```

How would I write the WHERE clause for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use between

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE   start_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `from_unixtime` to convert the unixtime column for comparison.

```
SELECT *
from employees
where from_unixtime(start_date) between now() - interval 30 day and now()
```